# Eclipse merge multi throws when throwing exceptions with same super class

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, objectmapper, throws

[ObjectMapper.readValue](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(byte[],%20java.lang.Class)) method Throws `IOException` and also its sub classes:
[JsonParseException](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException.html) and `JsonMappingException`

> ```
> extended by java.io.IOException
>           extended by com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
>               extended by com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
> ```

For the following code:

```
return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, VO.class);
```

Eclipse suggest and generate a valid surround with try **single** catch for multiple exceptions with same super class:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    Helpers.Debug(e);
}
```

But for throws it only suggest multiple throws:

```
throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
```

Is there a way in Eclipse to suggest/generate a single super class throws as `throws IOException`?

Comment: your `catch` example is *not* a multi-catch. i am confused about what you are asking for.

Comment: @Serge multi exceptions in one catch

Comment: In your example all exceptions which are derived from IOException will be cauthg.  A catch in java 8  allows you to catch exceptions listed there, i.e. `catch (ExcA | ExcB | ExcC ex)`. I would say that the latter is the multi-catch.

Comment: @Serge updated my answer to be more clear